# apex:param not recognized by document.getElementById()

Tags: visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce

I'm not sure if apex:form is supposed to show up as something on the HTML, but I don't see it and document.getElementById() is not finding it. This is what I have:

```
<apex:page id="parampage">
    <apex:form id="paramform">
      <apex:param name="param" id="param" value="123"/>
    </apex:form> 
<apex:page>
```

These are the results when I do a JS call:

1. `alert('{!$Component.parampage.paramform}')` result: `parampage:paramform` (as expected)
2. `alert('{!$Component.parampage.paramform.param}')` result: `parampage:paramform:param` (as expected)
3. `document.getElementById('{!$Component.parampage.paramform}')` result: returns the expected object
4. `document.getElementById('{!$Component.parampage.paramform.param}')` result: `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apex:param` is a logical construct that represents a parameter to some "managed" element (e.g. an element that uses the apex namespace). Technically, your code shouldn't compile, as [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) for this element states:

```
A parameter for the parent component.
The <apex:param> component can only be a child of the following components:
<apex:actionFunction>
<apex:actionSupport>
<apex:commandLink>
<apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputText>
<flow:interview>
```

Regardless, it doesn't generate any sort of element that you can simply grab by HTML ID. Instead, it's used to define the parameters that will be placed into a given function call back on the server.

For example, within an `apex:actionFunction`, it defines values that can be passed by JavaScript, and those parameters will be passed to the controller.